# Set the page number when combining pdf reports on telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I use [telerik reporting](https://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) to generate PDF reports in an ASP.NET MVC app, then i combine them into a single one using [iText Sharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp).

Each report has a page number, that i set using the `PageNumber` binding on the designer:

[image: pageNumber]

The `PageNumber` is starting from 1 for each report, so when i combine them i have something like; [1, 2, 3], [1, 2] ...

How do i tell the report to start the page number from a specific number so that i will have a consistent report [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..]?

```
public class ReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
{
    private byte[] GenerateReport<TReport, TData>(TData data) where TReport : Report, new()
    {
        Report reportDefinition =  new TReport();            
        reportDefinition.DataSource = data;                        
        ReportProcessor processor = new ReportProcessor();
        RenderingResult result = processor.RenderReport("PDF", new InstanceReportSource() {ReportDocument = reportDefinition},
            new Hashtable());
        if (result.HasErrors)
        {
            throw new AggregateException("There were errors in the reportGeneration");
        }

        return result.DocumentBytes;
    }

    public byte[] GenerateMyReport(TheReportViewModel reportVM)
    {
        return GenerateReport<TheReportDefinedUsingTheDesigner,TheReportViewModel>(reportVM);
    }
}
```

I generate multiple reports using `GenerateMyReport` then i combine them using *iText Sharp*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Combine the multiple reports in telerik we can use report book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

The page binding has to be set to `=Cint(PageNumber) + Cint(Fields.StartPageNumber)`

[image]

Where `PageNumber` is a predefined telerik report field, and `StartPageNumber` is a property that you add to you report's ViewModel